# Mongo db add new field to a collection and update if field already exists

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I have mongo collection array as below

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 7f841cef13cfcdba230019e2
)
[id] => 33
[name] => Adam
[table] => people
```

I want to add a field count to existing one

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 7f841cef13cfcdba230019e2
)
[id] => 33
[name] => Adam
[count] => 0
[table] => people
```

If count is already set , then update the array.

I have used 'update' method, but need to change the all array instead of one field. How I can do this with php ?

Comment: Question is unclear. How to you want to update the array if the count is already set?

Comment: @Thilo If `count` is not in array add `count` with corresponding value to array, then if count present in array just update the value of `count` . The count can be changed daily. If new person is added, `count` will not be added to array at first. It will be added later to array.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Do you want `count` to be always zero? Or the number of elements of this "array"? And what array is that? There is no array in the document you show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to set the `count` field to a given value (and creating the field if not present yet) without changing anything else , you can use the `$set` operator:

```
{ $set : { count: 0 }}
```

Answer (score -2):

use `update` function, like:

```
 $collection->update('$set'=>array("_id" => new MongoID("id of document")), 
                     array("new fiels" => "value of field"));
```